# How to customize the customer registration form?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, template

I want to modify **the customer registration form** in *Magento 1.9*.

There are two forms both under templates **1. Customer** and **2. Persistent.**

So which template should be modified ?

Because I have made changes in both the templates but still the original form is getting displayed.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/48050/problem-with-my-phtml-file-in-magento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System > Configuration > Developer (under Advanced) > Debug (then change store scope to Website View in top left) > Template Path Hints` (change to Yes), and then refresh front end page.

OR

Use free extension called **Easy Template Path Hints** with which you can just turn on the template path hints both for frontend and backend easily using query strings.

You will get to know the file from which it is called.

Answer (score 6):

You have to change in below template file for custom change.

```
app\design\frontend\{package_name}\{theme_name}\template\persistent\customer\form\register.phtml
```

You have to flush cache storage or flush magento cache.

Try this, worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the persistent form is used.

The only way to make Magento use the original customer form is by disabling the `Mage_Persistent` module (by setting true to false in `app/etc/modules/Mage_Persistent.xml`)

To modify the template, **do not edit the original template.** Copy the original template to `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` and you can start modify this file.