# Product View.phtml Modification 1.9.2.4 Move Tab Description

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, template, product-view

i have delete the Short description and price add to cart size collors now are on the place i want i have try to move the code for description but than i get a blank page .

maybe you can suggest me wich code i have to move that the description is after add to card and add this .

[image]

code please follow this link [CODE LINK](http://paste.ofcode.org/M7FqYuThWaPQDz6RQY8rqU)

update [image]

Comment: try to find solution using this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142522/45103

Comment: please check right click of mouse on space area and check rightside of that div tag, otherwise share with me link i give you better solution.

Comment: Have you try my suggested code ?

Comment: link product http://muslimas-shop.com/en/floral-dress-black-benin.html

Comment: hello , sorry thanks for your help :-) http://paste.ofcode.org/nKxdCLEETtYYzT5Ee6dUuh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your file code, you need to adjust div tag if your site is responsive i hope its works well:

go to your file number: 416
cut this code:

```
<div class="product-collateral"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description'); ?></div>
```

and paste after line number : 220
and check this

Comment: works but no w i have space between add this and description . please look update .  i post picture

Comment: a sorry foget in stress , to say thanks for help

Comment: May be there is a padding or marging first you need to check its padding or margin than, you need to add css like padding:0 ;margin:0;

Answer (score 0):

Add below code just after `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addthis_sharetool'); ?>`

```
<div class="product-collateral">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('description'); ?>
</div>
```