# I want to know the path of file. Anyone please help

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

I want to know, where the **Submit invoice** button is declared.[image]

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142522/45103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/invoice/create/items.phtml**  line `124`

```
<div class="a-right">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('submit_button') ?>
</div>
```

block for creating the button

**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Invoice/Create/Items.php**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check template and block file using Teamplate and Block Path hint. for enable template and block path in in magento you can just run below query in database.

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

After check path you can update value to 0 or also can remove this entry.