# How to change width in product view page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

I am converting my magento ecommerence theme into a theme more appropriate for a non profit organization, by removing all the features that appear related to an eCommerce shopping cart.   This is my product view page.  http://narsol.org/funding/narsol_events/nac2017reg.html

I need to tighten it up and center it.   Can someone tell me where to modify the code to change the width of the table?

Thank you.

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142522/45103 mostly it is `catalog/product/view.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

As per the link you given I can see the fields are in within the div of class **product-options** with style "with=100%" in **styles.css** in line 5632. Just change that with.

The code is coming from catalog\product\view\options\wrapper.phtml as shown below :

```
<div class="product-options" id="product-options-wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?>
<?php if ($this->hasRequiredOptions()):?>
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
<?php endif;?>
</div>
```