# How to remove Social Media Icons from Product View page?

Tags: template, magento-1.9.2.0, social-buttons

I am looking everywhere in the Admin panel and in the file manager.  I can not find where to remove the social media icons from under the "Add to Cart" button.   Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you using any extension for product sharing.

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142522/45103

Comment: No I am not.  I think this is part of the theme.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to catalog_product_view.xml in your theme

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.social" remove="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check following

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.sharing" as="sharing" template="catalog/product/view/sharing.phtml"/>
```

in the app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml file.

You may remove this in your theme file.

Answer (score -2):

Add this to your custom-style.css:

```
.product-shop-social {
   display:none;
}
```