# Magento 1.9 add to cart button validation

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I am new in Magento field. can you buddy help me to make understand how "add to cart button" validation HTML filed can find and works .? I reached

> /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml.
>
> /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/catalog.xml
>
> /var/www/html/magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

`/catalog/product/view.phtml` in this folder what should I analyze to understand about "add to cart" button validation please tell me to step by step with folder and directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Find **Add to Cart** Button HTML

```
<button type="button" title="Add to Cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

`onclick` it will call

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form'); // prototype VarienForm object.

productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
        var form = this.form;
        var oldUrl = form.action;

        if (url) {
           form.action = url;
        }
        var e = null;
        try {
            this.form.submit();
        } catch (e) {
        }
        this.form.action = oldUrl;
        if (e) {
            throw e;
        }

        if (button && button != 'undefined') {
            button.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

As you go through each input field of `product_addtocart_form` you will get validation class added into field.

get list of validation class on [inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/).

to find location of each HTML fields refer this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/142522/45103).